# Is it possible to make init stop restarting one of it's "services"?

Tags: applications, linux, superuser, services

My `init` is making the `eris` persistent, I don't know if the `/system/bin/eris` is important to keep android's good functionality but at this moment this "service" (the quotation marks are because i stopped the service from the terminal but the process of the path `/system/bin/eris` is persistent I just can't kill it) I wanna know if is possible to kill it once for all or at least `cat` the `init` binary or eris bin.

By the way i want to kill it because eris is listening to a port before even the initial page of the phone shows up, so likely it is receiving and sending info to an unkown machine

Comment: `eris` isn't an Android's service but muse be added by OEM. Which phone is it and what Android version it has? You can delete service's `*.rc` file or add `disabled` keyword to stop from auto starting. Adding `oneshot` will stop it from restarting once killed.

Comment: it is an Samsung Galaxy J2 Prime with the default android (I don't know the version) how do I edit the init tho? Where do I write oneshot/disabled ?

Comment: You need to find out the `.rc` file in which this service is stated. Common locations are `/`, `/system/etc/init` and `/vendor/etc/init`. You need root privileges to edit init's `.rc` files.

Comment: First I wanna thank you for all the support you're giving me, second I actually did find and cat the iti.rc and to my surprise eris has both: disabled and oneshot attached to it. Still the process keeps coming back, I'll check more info in the etc. One thing I noticed is that the /etc/eris.confg is missing the "wlan0" line

Comment: I'm going to try to kill one the processes being called by the init and put an strace to the init process, this may point me to the root of the problem, since eris is a oneshot service some other process must be calling for the init

Comment: A quick `strings` on `eris` binary shows that this service has something to do with [Samsung Knox VPN](https://docs.samsungknox.com/whitepapers/knox-platform/virtual-private-networks.htm) that makes use of StrongSwan. So be cautious while playing with it.

Comment: I just killed the process while tracing init and it was pretty shocking: a new PID appeared just to call init and them disapeared creating the copy of eris. This misterious process is now inactivated I wish I could get it's path. Just looking for the PID is looks like a kworker but of course this is a heuristic hypothesis

Comment: You can check the dependencies of services to figure out if some other service wants `eris`. But I think stopping this service would break some normal functionality of your device. Stock ROMs always suck by putting such closed source and undocumented mysterious stuff to get control of users activities.

Comment: Now I put strace on the eris binary itself and it is showing a PID that is not listed neither in ps neither in /proc I will keep investigating

Comment: pwdx is not working for some reason and this is getting weird

Comment: Do `readlink /proc/PID/cwd`

Comment: it just displays a bar (as if it is root), (exactly like pwdx is doing) the thing is in the /proc/PID the exe of this hidden process is /system/bin/eris too!

Comment: That "bar" must be root directory `/` and it's expected. `zygote` runs as root process with cwd `/`.

Comment: Note that you can't simply edit a *.rc file that lives under `/`, because it'll be regenerated afresh after a reboot.

Comment: true, Death Mask, luckily the rc seems fine it has oneshot and disabled I'm playing with strace to see if i can find the source apk/process behind this articulation